# Область видимости переменной

Tags: global-variables, массивы, php

Есть у меня несколько файлов с переводами, все они загружаются в зависимости от языковой сессии.

```
$lang = array(
    'lng_title'       => 'Привет мир',
    'lng_description' => '',
    'lng_keywords'    => '',
    'lng_index'       => 'На главную',
    'lng_back'        => 'Назад',
);
```

Но дело в том, что в большинстве файлов я не могу использовать этот массив. 
Что можно придумать?

Comment: Сделайте синглтон, который при первом вызове загружает эти данные в себя.

Comment: @Etki, а других вариантов нету?

Comment: Можете приложить структуру файлов, там где не работает и желательно порядок инклудов

Comment: Либо попробуйте сделать константу

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, делаешь класс-родителя (**parrent.php**),
в его **__construct** пихаешь получение перевода:

```
class parrent {
   private $lang;

   function __construct(){
      $this->lang = get_session_lang();
   }
}
```

затем в child.php пользуешься )

```
class child extends parrent {
  function foo(){
    $title = $this->lang['title'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Процедурный вариант есть? Просто у меня скрипт из 4х файлов, и использовать классы там будет не разумно..

Comment: @Алексей Дорохов parrot с двумя r, parent с одной

@Rnddev

> Просто у меня скрипт из 4х файлов, и использовать классы там будет не разумно.

c чего бы?

Answer (score 0):

В скрипте, где хотите использовать массив, в верху скрипта пишите `global $lang;`

Comment: Если бы это работало, я бы, наверное, не создавал вопрос :)

Comment: @Rnddev, это старо, как шкура мамонта, но работает и до шестой версии будет работать наверняка. В методах и функциях своя область видимости, поэтому там тоже надо запускать global.

Comment: @Etki, использую вне методов и функций.

Comment: @Etki, даже так не работает:

`include './lang/ru.php';
global $lang;
echo $lang['lng_index'];`

Comment: @Rnddev, php 5.5.9, работает как с global, так и без. Вы уверены, что файл подключается, а ошибки не замутированы? У вас отсчет пути пойдет от cwd, а не от папки с текущим файлом.